# Getting the authorization token in mpesa api using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mpesa

When getting the access_token from the mpesa API using nodejs, you run code like below

```
var request = require('request'),
    consumer_key = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_KEY",
    consumer_secret = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET",
    url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials"
    auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(consumer_key + ":" + consumer_secret).toString("base64");

    request(
      {
        url : url,
        headers : {
          "Authorization" : auth
        }
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        // TODO: Use the body object to extract OAuth access token
      }
    )
```

The Buffer method that is used to generate the auth value used during Authorization is deprecated in Node. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

> The Buffer() and new Buffer() constructors are not recommended for use
>   due to security and usability concerns. Please use the new
>   Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() construction
>   methods instead.

[Read More about the alternative of new Buffer() here](https://nodejs.org/fr/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/)

Answer (score 0):

I have received the access token quite successfully using the same method. Here is my code

```js
const request = require('request');

exports.mpesaAuth = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    const auth = new Buffer(
        `${process.env.MPESA_KEY}:${process.env.MPESA_SECRET}`
    ).toString('base64');
    request({
            url: process.env.MPESA_URL,
            headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}` }

        },
        (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    body
                });
            }
        },
    );
});
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the Buffer deprecation, you need to use `Buffer.from`. `Request` is also deprecated, I now use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Here's the code in ES6:

```
  import axios from 'axios'
  const consumer_key = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_KEY";
  const consumer_secret = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET";
  const url = process.env.SAF_AUTH_URL;
  const Authorization = `Basic ${new Buffer.from(
    `${consumer_key}:${consumer_secret}`,
    'utf-8'
  ).toString('base64')}`;
  axios
    .get(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // Handle Success
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       //Handle your error
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

## Update 2023

As illustrated below, generating an Mpesa access token in NodeJs can be simplified using the Axios networking library.

```
 let appKeySecret = `${CONSUMER_KEY}:${CONSUMER_SECRET}`;
            let authorization = base64.Base64.encode(appKeySecret);

            axios({
              method: 'get',
              url: "https://api.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials",
              headers: {'Authorization': `Basic ${authorization}`, 'cache-control':'no-cache'}
            }).then(apiResponse =>{

              let  response = apiResponse.data;

            let  accesstoken =  response.access_token;

});
```